# setTimeout differenet behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript

Thease two code look same but they behaving differently. I got to know the javascript work with event loop, It add the event in the queue then execute one by one. But here they work differently

```
setTimeout(a,0)
alert(1)
alert(2)
function a(){
alert(0)
}
```

//1
//0
//2

```
setTimeout(function(){
alert(0)
},0)
alert(1)
alert(2)
```

//1
//2
//0

I notice that `setTimeout` work differently with named function. If javascript gives priority to names function then why it is not alerting it first time

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hdoh83kq/1/ - looks fine

Comment: Ok fine, It seems it works differently with alerts

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hdoh83kq/2/

Comment: try console.log it will work fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdoh83kq/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Why alert(0) is executing after alert(1). Can you please it theoretically

Comment: for me both the alert(0) are coming after alert 1 & 2 - so the order is `1,2,1,2,0,0`

Comment: @ArunPJohny:  On firefox alert(0) is coming after alert(1) but in chrome alert(0) is coming after 1 and 2

Comment: @amit I think the root cause for this is the optional behavior as given in the spec http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html

Comment: You only alert 0, 1 and 2 but you say the the code alerts `//1//2//3` -- where did the 3 come from?

Comment: If you see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hdoh83kq/4/ - it is not consistent sometimes `1,0,2,101,100,102`

Comment: See also http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: it might be because of `Optionally, pause while waiting for for the user to acknowledge the message` - so chrome might not implement it while FF is implementing it